Azure Cosmos DB Change Feed Processor: High Request Volume to Lease Container
We are using the Azure Cosmos DB Change Feed Processor to process changes from a monitored container. The lease container is configured to manage lease documents for the change feed processor. However, we experienced extremely high request volumes to the lease container, causing throttling (HTTP 429 errors) and unnecessary overhead.
Changed feed apps deployed to the AKS.
C# code
    private async Task StartProcessingAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var sourceDb = client.GetDatabase(DatabaseConstants.Components.Id);
    var sourceContainer = sourceDb.GetContainer(DatabaseConstants.Components.ComponentsContainerId);

    var leaseContainerProperties = new ContainerProperties(
        DatabaseConstants.Components.LeaseContainerId,
        DatabaseConstants.PropertyPaths.Id);
    var leaseContainer = await sourceDb.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(leaseContainerProperties, cancellationToken: stoppingToken);
    
    await sourceContainer.GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder(DataProviderConstants.ProcessorName, 
            (IReadOnlyCollection<object> changes, CancellationToken token) => processor.HandleChangesAsync(changes, token))
        .WithInstanceName(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(DataProviderConstants.InstanceEnvironmentVariableName) ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        .WithLeaseContainer(leaseContainer)
        .WithPollInterval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_settings.PollIntervalInMilliseconds))
        .WithMaxItems(_settings.MaxItems)
        .WithLeaseAcquireNotification(_onLeaseAcquiredAsync)
        .WithLeaseReleaseNotification(_onLeaseReleaseAsync)
        .WithErrorNotification(_onErrorAsync)
        .Build()
        .StartAsync();
}

Initial Setup

Target Framework: .NET 8.0
Polling Interval (WithPollInterval): 5 seconds
Batch Size (WithMaxItems): 10
Throughput of Lease Container: 400 RU/s
Number of Pods (Replicas): 2
Monitored Container Physical Partitions: 1 (confirmed by a single lease document)

Observed Issues
Excessive Lease Container Requests
With 2 pods and a single lease document, each pod competed for the same lease, generating redundant queries and updates to the lease container. In the setup with 2 pods request volume: ~90,000 requests per minute (attached screen with total requests)
Throttling (HTTP 429)
The lease container was under-provisioned at 400 RU/s, causing frequent throttling and retries, leading to a retry storm that amplified the request volume.
Inefficient Lease
Configuration
Default lease renewal, expiration, and acquire intervals were too aggressive, causing unnecessary lease management operations.
Changes Implemented
Reduced Pods to a Single Instance
Since there was only 1 physical partition and thus only 1 lease document, we reduced the number of pods to 1 replica.
Result: Request volume dropped significantly, from ~90,000 requests per minute to ~23,400 requests per minute.
I have the following questions

We still have 429 errors and it seems something is wrong even with a single replica. Is this expected? For example, is 350 requests per second to the lease container a normal amount for a single replica managing a single physical partition?

Does it make sense to override the default behavior for the following settings?



WithPollInterval
WithMaxItems
WithLeaseConfiguration (acquireInterval, renewInterval, expirationInterval)

If so, what are the best practices for adjusting these settings to reduce request volume without impacting performance?

In the case of a single physical partition, does it make sense to have 2 replicas running, or will this only increase pressure on Cosmos DB? Specifically, does running 2 replicas provide any added value for fault tolerance in this scenario, or does it simply create unnecessary contention and increase lease-related traffic?



UPDATED:
Decided to redeploy with overrided configuration for:

WithPollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000)
WithMaxItems = 1000
WithLeaseConfiguration (acquireInterval = 30 seconds, renewInterval = 30 seconds, expirationInterval = 90 seconds)

Here is updated chart with counts of requests over time (it's dropped a lot, but this growing over time):



Are you sure you have just 2 instances? Take a look at the official documentation for tinkering with the intervals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/change-feed-processor?tabs=dotnet#advanced-lease-configuration.
PollInterval is only used when there are no changes, but if there are changes, then the goal is to deliver them as soon as possible. Increasing the MaxItems will decrease the lease requests because it uses less requests to transfer the same amount of docs, and reduces the volume of Handler executions. Each execution checkpoints (lease request).
